# Issue in Future.cancel() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a below runnable task which is run by using  `ThreadPoolExecutor threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(1));` This ensures that there will be only one waiting task in the queue.

```
protected void waitAndSweep(final String symbol) {
    try { 

        runnable = new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
             // long sweepTime = symbolInfo.getSweepTime(symbol);
              // long timeSinceLastSweep = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSliceSentTime;
              boolean sliceDone = Quant.equals(wave.getCommitedQuantity() % getSliceQuantity(),0);
              if(sliceDone){
                long timeSinceLastSliceQtySent = lastSliceSentTime == 0 ? getInterval() : System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSliceSentTime;
                long waitTime = timeSinceLastSliceQtySent >= getInterval() ? 0 : getInterval() - timeSinceLastSliceQtySent;
                logTradeEvent("waitAndSweep", symbol, "waittime: " + waitTime);
                if (waitTime > 0){
                  Thread.sleep(waitTime);
                }
              }

              callSweep(symbol);
            } catch(InterruptedException ie){
              ie.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              logEvent(StrategyEntry.ERROR, "waitAndSweep", symbol,
                  "Exception caught...", e);
            }            
          }
        };

      self = threadPoolExecutor.submit(runnable);   
    }catch(RejectedExecutionException re){
      /* this exception will be thrown when wait and sweep is called more than twice.
       * threadPoolExecutor can have one running task and one waiting task.
       * */
      System.out.print(re);
      }catch (Exception e) {
      logEvent(StrategyEntry.ERROR, "waitAndSweep", symbol,
          "Exception caught...", e);
    }
  }
```

Consider the caller A :

```
private void callerA(){
waitandsweep();
waitandsweep();}
```

this craetes two task one will be running and another waiting in the queue.

Consider the callerB:

```
private void callerB(){
self.cancel(true);
waitandsweep();}
```

Expecting callerB to cancel all the tasks invoked by A. 
Actually it is not happening.. task invoked by caller B is getting rejected because already one task is waiting in the queue. Can you please tell why this behaviour happens?

edit 1 : How to cancel running task of executor?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that `Future.cancel(boolean)` doesn't remove the task from the queue. The Task will not be executed, once it will be pulled by the `Executor` but until then its still in the queue

try to use `threadPoolExecutor.purge();` right after `cancel();` it will try to remove the canceled tasks

cancelling a running Task is not that easy, you could try following:
call `cancel(true);` it will set `Thread.interrupted()` to `true`. Now in your Task check on some steps that value and so you can decide to skip next steps of your task

Comment: What is the way to remove the task from the queue. and will the running task be terminated by cancel method?

Comment: @user5367186 you can't actually "terminate" a task. You need to check "interrupted"/"isCanceled"- values in your Task

Comment: @user5367186 it will be automatically interrupted and an `InterruptedException` will be thrown. So if you call `cancel(true);`, you will land in `catch(InterruptedException ie)`

Comment: @user5367186 yes, it will interrupt it by throwing `InterruptedException`